# How to reset the position within the dropdown of a Silverlight AutoCompleteBox

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, controls, autocomplete

Lets say I have an AutoCompleteBox with 1000 items.

1. A user first types two characters returning a broad result set (for example, 100 items).
2. They then scroll to the bottom of the list and...
3. They then select the last item which closes the dropdown.
4. The user then returns to the AutoCompleteBox and enters a more refined search returning, say, 25 items.
5. Because the previously selected item was at the bottom of the dropdown, the AutoCompleteBox shows the last element(s) of the new search result, instead of displaying the first items at the top of the list.

How do I force the AutoCompleteBox to display the results starting with the first item in the list?

Comment: The AutoCompleteBox exploses events for when the dropdown is opening and closing.  Have you tried resetting the selected item in these events?

Comment: I figured that would trigger the selecteditemchanged event, closing the dropdown and triggering another series of things.

Comment: I went back and started to try to change the seleteditem in the dropdownopening event, but realized I don't know how.  I don't know how to reference the first item of the filtered list of items being displayed in the list.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a blind guess based on the default control templates.  In `DropdownOpening` event:-

```
 var sv = ((FrameworkElement)sender).FindName("ScrollViewer") As ScrollViewer;
 if (sv != null)
   sv.VerticalOffset = 0;
```

Comment: Ooooh... so close.  I thought it was going to work for a minute, but got this error:  "System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"   But Thanks!  You just made a positive adjustment to my understanding of the object.

Comment: PS... the ScrollViewer is not found in the sender (AutoCompleteBox) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not much of an answer, but I thought I would share what I discovered, even though it does not solve the problem. I tried all the following in the `DropDownOpening`event.

1. Set the `SelectedItem` to null. - Failed.
2. Follow what Anthony suggested. - Failed. First off, `sender` is `AutoCompleteBox` and does not contain `ScrollViewer`. Second, `VerticalOffset` is read-only.
3. I checked all the variables in `AutoCompleteBox` and found that it has a non-public variable called `DropDownPopup` that is an instance of `System.Windows.Control.PopupHelper`. I could not find it in that library though. It does however, contain a `Popup` property with a variable `VerticalOffset`. However, I tried to inherit `AutoCompleteBox` and was unable to access that variable, so I suspect it must be private.